# Go Coding Style - relative import of package

Tags: go

Suppose I have a go project that includes many package. in example we can see this

```
-Project
---A
----aa
----ab
---B
----ba
----bb
```

Now while coding If i need to use methods of package **aa** into my **bb** package the standered way is to import like

```
import "github.com/user/project/A/aa"
```

But I have seen this package importing supports also relative import like

```
import "./../../A/aa"
```

That will also import that package and allow mw to use the methods.

Now my question is - I didn't see any one importing like this. So is this type of **relative importing is  prohibited? or it is allowed but using this is only a bad practice of coding?**

Comment: Relative imports generate more problems than they solve. Search the golang-nuts mailing list for lots of discussions about it.